# Making POST request to Vuforia's Web Services always results in "Fail", even though PUT request always works using same approach/body

Tags: rest, http, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am developing an Android app in Unity. I am trying to make UnityWebRequests to work with Vuforia's Web Services API. Currently every method works - GET/PUT/DELETE, but I cannot POST anything, I always get an error:

```
Error:Generic/unknown HTTP error
Response code:400
```

Even though according to Vuforia's [documentation](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Solution/How-To-Use-the-Vuforia-Web-Services-API.html) POST requires the same request body as PUT and I am generating it using the same approach:

```
public string CreateNewUpdateBody(Text name, Text width, RawImage image, Toggle active_flag, Text application_metadata)
{
    dynamic BodyData = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name.text))
    {
        BodyData.name = name.text; // mandatory for post
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(width.text))
    {
        BodyData.width = float.Parse(width.text); // mandatory for post
    }
    if (image.texture != null)
    {
        Texture2D texture = (Texture2D)image.texture;
        BodyData.image = System.Convert.ToBase64String(ImageConversion.EncodeToJPG(texture)); // mandatory for post
    }
    if (active_flag.interactable)
    {
        BodyData.active_flag = active_flag.isOn;
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(application_metadata.text))
    {
        BodyData.application_metadata = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(application_metadata.text));
    }
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BodyData);

    Debug.Log("Body data: " + json);

    return json;
}
```

Then I send the web request like this:

```
private IEnumerator PostTarget(MonoBehaviour mono, string postBody)
{
    var request = UnityWebRequest.Post(url + "/targets", postBody);

    SetHeaders(request); // Must be done after setting the body

    Debug.Log("Starting request " + request.method + " " + request.url);

    yield return request.SendWebRequest();

    while (!request.isDone) yield return null;

    if (request.isHttpError || request.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Request was not completed");
        Debug.LogError("Error:" + request.error + " Response code:" + request.responseCode);
        Debug.LogError(request.downloadHandler.text); // result_code is always just "Fail"
        mono.StopAllCoroutines();
        yield break;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Request completed successfuly!");
        Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
    }

    response = JsonUtility.FromJson<ResponsePostNewTarget>(request.downloadHandler.text);

    Debug.Log("\nCreated target with id: " + response.target_id);
}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions? I appreciate the time you take to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything works BUT posting data, either 1 vuforia doesn't support it or 2 (most likely) you're missing something.

Try adding this to your request

```
private UploadHandler GetUploadHandler(string postBody)
{
    UploadHandler handler = new UploadHandlerRaw(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postBody));
    handler.contentType = "application/json";
    return handler;
}
```

And call it after SetHeaders

```
request.uploadHandler = GetUploadHandler(postBody);
```

Comment: I can't believe it works! I've spent the whole day yesterday trying to find what's wrong. The only thing that I needed to change in your answer was actually assign the UploadHandler **before** SetHeaders, otherwise I get a response code 401 "AuthenticationFailure". Can you explain why we have to create the UploadHandler manually, even though we can set the body as we create the request with `UnityWebRequest.Post(url + "/targets", postBody);` ?

Comment: Many things in unity are just trial and error really. The documentation for UnityWebRequest is very poor, and the knowledge I gathered are scattered throughout my projects. But probably the issue is the default contentType is not application/json, so when you encoded the string in the post, it went with the default encoding and your backend wasn't expecting it.
I'm glad it worked out for you.